# Book (probably for children/young teens) with a teaspoon that sighs a lot

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm trying to find a fantasy book I read, back in 2000 or shortly after. Unfortunately, I remember next to nothing about it. It would have been aimed at a young audience (I was in my early teens when I read it). I read it in German, but I don't know if that was the original language.

What I do remember is that one character was a little teaspoon that seemed quite sad all the time and sighed a lot. I don't think it ever spoke, it just sighed. A lot. It was a companion/sidekick to the main character. The main character and any other companions and major characters were not cutlery, and it didn't take place in a kitchen or even "civilisation" setting - more like woods/wilderness.

My mum thinks there may have been illustrations in the book, similar to those in *The Edge Chronicles* (the Twig trilogy), and at first I thought those might be the books, but I can't find any mention of a teaspoon in the Twig books (I checked the wiki, as I don't have the books here).

Answer (score 7):

[*Muddle Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muddle_Earth) (2003) by Paul Stewart and Chris Riddell fits nicely. Similar to the Twig books (same authors​), illustrated, and an enchanted (IIRC) teaspoon who braved many adventures during the trilogy.

> Dropping down out of the sky towards the sandpit, the tiny teaspoon was nearing the end of its brief flight. With a soft swooshing noise - **and the hint of a little sigh** - the teaspoon landed in soft sand and buried itself up to its handle. [...]
>
> As it dropped down into the pocket, **the teaspoon let out a little sigh**. It was warm and moist and smelly in the goblin's trousers, and - the teaspoon trembled - very, very dark.

Comment: Funnily enough, [the last time this was given as a story-ID answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187579/98028), the querent's username was "Spoon"! (disclaimer: the answer there is also mine)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Strangely, despite the teaspoon sounding very similar, the book doesn't ring a bell at all, so I don't think this is it.

Comment: You mean there are *two* books with sighing teaspoons?!?!

Comment: On the one hand I'd say there are enough books that ideas are bound to pop up twice. On the other hand it is oddly specific. But neither my mum nor I recognise any part of the plot summary or any of the characters, so it seems like that's the case, yes.